# Handlebars.js wont compile/output my template/data

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js, template-engine

I'm playing around with Handlebars.js and trying to compile a small template. I am only using Handlebars.js and nothing more.
I am working locally on my computer, and not via any form of server.

my "html" looks like this. nothing special.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="js/vendor/handlebars.min-4.0.4.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script id="menu-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
            <h1>{{title}}</h1>
        </script>


        <section id="menu">

        </section>


        <script src="js/menu.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

And my JS is

```
var source = document.getElementById('menu-template').innerHTML;
var template = Handlebars.compile(source);
var data = {title: "test"};

document.getElementById('menu').innerHTML = template(data);
```

It seems that template() does not return anything, i don't get any result except what looks like a empty string.

And i have been playing around with this for a few hours and searching the internet for answers but no result.

Am i doing anything wrong here?

// Edit added the rest of the html page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code seems correct just make sure the Handlebars.js file is properly included before the existing script tag.

Ref for Handlebars CDN : https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/4.0.4/handlebars.js

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i have updated my original post with more html.
So you can see that i have put the script tags correct. I have also tried to putt the handlebar script tag over the menu.js script tag, but nothing changed.

Comment: I changed my Handelbar script tag from my local copy to the link you provided me with and it worked.

But it's the same version.
Da f?